# UIView smaller than another UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have an UIView high 30, than i add an UITableView as subview with 30 as origin.y. Because the table remains “under” the main view I cannot select the cells. Consequently I have implemented this method:

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Tocco intercettato");
    if (oldSet && oldEvent) {
        [table touchesEnded:oldSet withEvent:oldEvent];
    }
    oldSet = touches;
    oldEvent = event;
    [table touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [table touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

The taps work, but the slides does not work and consequently I cannot slide the table.  Some idea in order to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the touches from an overlying UIView to an underlying UITableView does not work (as you're seeing, the taps go through but not the scrolling movements). This is because UITableView (as a subclass of UIScrollView) does all sorts of under-the-hood weirdness with the responder chain (your code is also kind of odd, where you call both touchesBegan and touchesEnded from the overlying view's touchesBegan method, but this isn't why you can't scroll the table).

A simple way to achieve what you want (assuming I've understood that correctly) is to override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method on your overlying view and have the method return the underlying UITableView (instead of `self`, which is the default implementation):

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)[self.superview.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    return tv;
}
```

Note that this code assumes the `UITableView` is the first view added to your view controller, and that the overlying `UIView` is added after that.

**Edit:** OK, after re-reading your question, I think I understand your question. You have a main view with a height of 30, and to that view you've added a UITableView at y = 30. I think adding this method to your main view will do what you need:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (point.y < self.frame.size.height) {
        return self;
    } else {
        return myTableView; // assumes myTableView is a reference to the
                            // UITableView that you've added
    }
}
```

Essentially, you're telling the OS to pass all touches on to `myTableView` if they're outside the bounds of your main view.

However, a simpler way would be to add both the 30-pixel-high main view (the orange thing) and the UITableView as subviews of another view (or view controller). That way, you wouldn't have to do anything kludgy to get your table to behave like a normal table.

Comment: Actually I've a tableView added as subview at an view (orange in the image) [link](http://cl.ly/1A312H2K0j2U3k2c2C2L). So I've to implement that method in my code?

Comment: As I suspected, I didn't actually understand your question. If the table is just added as a subview, why can't you just click/scroll it like normal? I'm not sure what you mean when you say the table view is "under" the main view.

Comment: The orange view is like a slider, I can pan up and down but the table is a subview of the orange view

Comment: And then the orange view is high 20

Comment: Well, I appreciate the check, but if your solution was something different than what I posted, you should post it as an answer to your own question and then select that as the correct answer.

Comment: Well, It's not brilliant :P I've made a 'mother' uiview :)